# Print different thing from same screen

Tags: usability, printing, many-options

I need some help on how to present many different print possibility from the same ribbon. Right now it is made as two print drop down action buttons, one to print the checklist and one to print the report, for each you can select if it should be with or without pictures from the drop down. Now i need to add the possibility to print the checklist for a chosen area (eg. select tasks in the garden instead of all tasks.)

[image]

How can a give the possibility to print different things without presenting many buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the system you have is getting too complex for the interaction model you are using - I would recommend just having a single print button (no options) that, when clicked, opens a dialogue or modal box where the various options can be explained more graphically (perhaps with small illustrations) allowing the user to make a more informed choice about the print output that they want - this should also cut down on unwanted prints and therefore means less trips to the printer for the user.

(Couldn't find a way to add images in comments)

The user clicks the print button and the get a little dialogue something like this:
[image: Print Dialogue]

Although, I would also add icons to demonstrate the different image options (Sorry - don't have time to do that right now)

Comment: I have thought about the same but there is not enough hours for that right now but it is a future wish. Therefor i would like to hear your ideas to make sure that is the best solution:)